# External script added to my react SPFx WebPart is not working in IE 11

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, reactjs, ie

I want you to help me with the IE11 issue. Thing is my SPFx web part was not working on the IE browser, I tried various Polyfills and some core-js modules but none of them worked. Later on, I found one of the scripts which worked on the local workbench but, when I uploaded my build to the SharePoint site, it didn't work. When I checked source script is added there but on SharePoint site that script is missing n view source. Below is code I have used to add the script to my web part component.

```
useEffect(function () {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.js?features=es5,es6,es2016,es2017%7Cgated&flags=gated&unknown=polyfill&callback=onPolyfillsLoad";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, []);
```

Let me know how would I make this code script to work on Prod.

Comment: Try installing this npm dependency in your project instead of adding the polyfill file from code: `npm i polyfill-service`

Comment: Its [NPM Reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/polyfill-service) and [GitHub Reference](https://github.com/financial-times/polyfill-service).

Comment: @GaneshSanap - Facing below issue while installing polyfill-service. 
 Error: Can't find Python executable "c:\Python\27\python.exe", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
I am also trying to set python variable via npm --add-python-to-path='true' --debug install --global windows-build-tools

nothing is working

Comment: ok. maybe it has some dependency on python. try using: https://github.com/Financial-Times/polyfill-library

Comment: Error: unhandle promise reject. 'root' is undefined

Comment: Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Unable to get property 'root' of undefined or null reference

Comment: have you tried @pnp/polyfill-ie11? it's part of pnp js which works for IE11 when you used for pnp js. check out https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/v1/documentation/polyfill/

Comment: @VeronaChen- Yes, I tried this too. Somehow it worked on local workbench but when I built package on Prod it failed and shown same errors.

Comment: Closing this out, as dropped IE support in my project.